# jQuery on() doesn't work on already added DOM items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".prev", function(){
    $(this).closest("div").find(".slider").animate({
        "left": "+=450px"
    }, 800, "easeInOutBack");
    return false;
});
```

Which works when new elements are added to the DOM, but it doesn't work for elements that are already in the DOM.

When I do this:

```
$(".prev").on("click", function(){
    $(this).closest("div").find(".slider").animate({
        "left": "+=450px"
    }, 800, "easeInOutBack");
    return false;
});
```

It works for elements in the DOM, but not new ones added to the DOM. Is there a way for me to get this to work for both without me having to write this 2 times, or make a call to another function?

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Shot]

So, Here is a more in depth description of how it works.

```
<div id="simple-pevs" style="padding-right: 20px;">
    <?php require_once __DIR__ . "/data/get/PEVSection.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Then When someone wants to add another section they click on the add button which then runs this code:

```
    $(".add-another-pev").click(function(){
        $.get("./data/get/PEVSection.php?pev="+pevGroup, function(data){
            $("#simple-pevs").append(data);
        });
        pevGroup++;
        return false;
    });
```

As you can see it is calling the same one that was pre-loaded in the php. The new one works (and any other additional ones added) with the click event and the fist one doesn't

**@ArunPJohny**

`console.log($(".prev"));` after a new element is added:

```
[a.prev, a.prev, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: ".prev", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
0: a.prev
1: a.prev
context: #document
length: 2
prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1]
selector: ".prev"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: The first snippet should work for both new and old elements. Please provide a jsfiddle showing otherwise.

Comment: You're running it in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: This has to work, can you try `$('body').on` instead

Comment: According to [this][1] the two methods you're using work differently.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10864892/503550

Comment: @G_M for linking in comments you can use the `[foo](link)` syntax

Comment: Here's a fiddle with it working for both: http://jsfiddle.net/CEves/1/

Comment: @KevinB So, I tested on jsFiddle, and it works. But on my page it does not...

Comment: @RyanNaddy see Michael Berkowski's comment - you need to put this inside a `document.ready` handler.  jsfiddle does this automatically (and invisibly)

Comment: document ready should not affect this code, he's binding directly to the document. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642156/does-this-code-need-to-be-in-a-document-ready/10642199#10642199

Comment: @RyanNaddy can you add a console.log in the event handler to check whether it is called but the animation is failed

Comment: Go over the symptoms of this problem. Using the delegation method results in it working only for new elements, using the non-delegation method makes it work only for existing elements. Chances are there's something different about the structure of new elements vs existing elements that is causing the real problem here. Please provide relevant html. (or the jsfiddle as originally asked for)

Comment: @ArunPJohny added it, nothing gets printed on ones that are already there. When I click the "Add" button to add another, then click the added one. it prints out the `console.log()` text

Comment: Can you do a `$('.prev')` and `$('.prev').length` in the console and see the results to make sure the class attributes are correct

Comment: @ArunPJohny See edits

Comment: as per you calculation how many `.prev` elements are present before new elements are added and how many new elements are added

Comment: @ArunPJohny When the page first loads there is one `.prev` class in the DOM. When I click the load button to load another block, then there are 2 `.prev` classes in the DOM, click it again now there are 3 `.prev` classes, and so on.

Comment: Found the problem. It was another function: `$("a").click(function(){return false;});` Why is it only causing this a link to break and not the others?

Comment: that affects all existing a links, not new ones. Your first snippet only affects new elements because existing elements were getting their event prevented before it bubbled to the document. The second snippet worked on existing elements because it was being triggered before the above click handler.

Comment: But I have other link elements that are pre-loaded, that it doesn't affect, and the JS works just fine on them.

Comment: If your function `$("a").click(function(){return false;});` is inside of doc ready, then only links that are currently on the page will be bound to that event; links pulled in as part async content won't be bound to that. Try `$("a").on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});` instead.

Also, be wary of `return false;` vs. `e.preventDefault();`

http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Comment: Your version of jQuery matters in this function. The event used to be written the way you have written it however if you are using the latest version, please see OQJF's comment - There is updated documentation on the jQuery website that he has quoted and linked to

Answer (score 2):

***Below is the content that I copied from Jquery official website, It can explain it very clearly***:
**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().** To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. **If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.**

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

Note: Delegated events do not work for SVG.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This is correct as of the latest version of jQuery - However OP has not provided which version of jQuery he is using

Answer (score -1):

No if you create new elements like this, then you need to rebind the event handler.

```
function bindHandler() {
    $(document).on("click", ".prev", function(){
        $(this).closest("div").find(".slider").animate({
            "left": "+=450px"
        }, 800, "easeInOutBack");
        return false;
    });
}
bindHandler();

$(".add-another-pev").click(function(){
    $.get("./data/get/PEVSection.php?pev="+pevGroup, function(data){
        $("#simple-pevs").append(data);
    });
    pevGroup++;

    bindHandler();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the correct usage of the .on() event in jQuery automatically handles the initial and re-binding of the event to avoid needing to do this