# Can i use function at the place of $( document ).ready(function() {}

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use function at the place of `$( document ).ready(function() {}` in jQuery?

Actually I am using this method and it is working fine. I am asking this to know is it make any problem in future or not? or is it a wrong method?

For example

```
function run_query
{
jquery code here
}
```

Comment: $(function () {}) is the alternative to using $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: Yes, you can omit dom ready, just make sure that your code doesn't execute until after the elements that it needs to interact with exist.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642156/does-this-code-need-to-be-in-a-document-ready

Comment: You mean like `$(document).ready(run_jquery)`

Comment: You could use: `$(run_query)`. This will call `run_query` function on document ready

Answer (score 2):

The `$(function(){ })` or `$(document).ready(function(){})` define event handlers that are fired on document ready event.  Document ready is fired when all the html is loaded onto the page, this includes images.  You don't have to define a page ready handler if you aren't doing any DOM manipulation or if you define your functions after the content has been loaded.

One thing to note, if you're doing any binding to elements directly they must be loaded onto the page before you try to bind to them.  What I mean by direct binding is `$("#id").on('event', handler)`.  You can also use delegate binding which is something like `$(document).on('event', '#id', handler)` or `$('altEl').on('event', 'el selector', handler)`, in this circumstance make sure that `altel` is loaded. Note that the `document` element will be loaded by the time javascript executes in the `<head>`.

Comment: I think you should refine your last paragraph since binding `.on` on document is not a good practice. and `$('el').on('event', 'el', func)` is not a direct binding and yet, it will not work without DOM ready.

Comment: Agreed, however, the reason I said on(document) is because if the javascript is defined in the <head> that will still work. You don't need to make sure any html is loaded.

Comment: Ohh but i totaly agree with that, but you said *"binding to elements directly they must be loaded onto the page before you try to bind to them. What I mean by direct binding is..."* which tell that "undirect binding (delegated events) does not need to wait the DOM to be ready", which is false. I know you know it, but the OP (or other users that need help) may not know that, hence why i said you should refine the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the other questions that have been posted about how javascript/html is loaded and executed when the page is sent to the client... Putting a function inside $(document) is only necessary when the code inside the function depends on elements inside the HTML which may have not loaded yet.

The best way to do it is to put your scripts at the bottom of the page, right before the end body

```
</body>
```

tag as then you don't have to worry about certain HTML elements not being loaded yet and it makes your site run faster as it won't have to wait for the javascript to execute in order to display the page.

Comment: Make sure to be aware if you're doing any manipulation with images they might not be loaded yet even after the html is parsed.  That is an abnormal circumstance but it's something to be aware of.